# How to detect css background url

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to make swipe effect to change background image but it stuck!

This is my code:

```
$('#AAA').swipeleft(function() {

   var BG = document.getElementById("AAA").style.backgroundImage;

   if (BG = "url('../Image/002.jpg')") {

      $('#AAA').css('background-image','url(../Image/003.jpg)');
   };

   if (BG = "url('../Image/003.jpg')") {

      $('#AAA').css('background-image','url(../Image/004.jpg)');
   };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your conditions should contain == operator. Not a single =. You want to compare those values, not assign.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes in the replacement images and the equals operator should be `==`, not `=`. Quotes are important when you are comparing a string to another. Please check them and you'll get that working. Here's a click-triggered example of the switch effect:

```js
$("#myDiv").click(function(){
  
  var BG = $(this).css("background-image");
  console.log(BG);
  if(BG == 'url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/")') {
    $(this).css("background-image", "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/300/')");
  } else if(BG == 'url("http://lorempixel.com/400/300/")') {  
    $(this).css("background-image", "url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/')");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div style="background:black url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/'); width: 200px; height: 200px;" id="myDiv"></div>
```